# Microstrip on FPC board

Tags: filter, batteries, microstrip, fpc

Do anyone know, what is the strange track on FPC board on image below?
My guess is, it is something like a microstrip track.
The image is for a FPC board, that measure cell voltage of batteries.

[image]

Comment: Looks like someones idea of a fuse.

Comment: if it is a fuse, why the second track of fuse , doesn't connect to anywhere?

Comment: When one fuses, connect the other ...